# Order created webhook in Bigcommerce only fires when creating order using store control panel

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce, webhooks

I'm working with Bigcommerce API using php. I've successfully created `store/order/created` webhook, but it only fires when I create the order using the store control panel, it's not working when I post an order to `orders` endpoint in the code even though my order has been successfully created.

The example order that I posted is like below:

```
    $product = new \stdClass();
    $product->product_id = 194;
    $product->sku = 'test-prod-1';
    $product->quantity = 1;

    $shippingAddress = new \stdClass();
    $shippingAddress->first_name    = "Trisha";
    $shippingAddress->last_name     = "McLaughlin";
    $shippingAddress->street_1      = "Mikonkatu 15A";
    $shippingAddress->city          = "Helsinki";
    $shippingAddress->zip           = "00100";
    $shippingAddress->country_iso2  = "FI";
    $shippingAddress->phone         = "0452507625";
    $orderData = array(
        'date_created' => 'Wed, 14 Nov 2012 19:26:23 +0000',
        'customer_id' => 1,
        'payment_method' => 'Cash',
        'external_source' => 'Test',
        'billing_address' => $shippingAddress,
        'status_id' => 11,
        'products' => array(
            $product
        )
    );
    $bcOrder = Bigcommerce::createOrder($orderData);
```

Anyone had the same issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are more likely to see `store/order/updated` correctly fire when a successful order has been placed. `store/order/created` may fire when an unsuccessful order was attempted and some other variables, but the first `store/order/updated` should correctly identify a new order in the system.